# weird GUI problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gui, ubuntu-gnome, gtk3

After I start ubuntu from a suspend, every box gets bounded by a white wrapper like thing. It is a recent problem and only gets removed when I logout and login or restart. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

What can I do about it? And why is it there, this is the first time I am suffering from this abnormality of ubuntu GUI.